# Why does $('selector').find not return the same object as $.find('selector')?

Tags: jquery

When I execute the following statements, why do I not get the same object?
   `console.log($('body').find('#myFormId'))`

and

`console.log($.find('#myFormId'))`

Please see my HTML below:

```
<body>
<form id="myFormId"></form>
</body>
```

I can see that the first statement returns a jQuery object, where as the second statement only returns a array with the DOM element in it.

Debugging the jQuery code I can see that the `context` argument in the Sizzle function is undefiend when executing the second statement, please see below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does $('selector').find not return the same object as $.find('selector')?

jQuery objects of the same DOM element are not the same object anyway.

```
$('body').find('#myFormId') === $('body').find('#myFormId')       // false
```

However, the underlying DOM objects will be the same.

```
$('body').find('#myFormId')[0] === $('body').find('#myFormId')[0] // true
$('body').find('#myFormId')[0] === $.find('#myFormId')[0]         // true
```

To test for equality, you can use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$('body').find('#myFormId').is( $('body').find('#myFormId') )     // true
$('body').find('#myFormId').is( $.find('#myFormId') )             // true
```

Demo: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/behura/embed?js,console)

---

*Note:* Using `$.find()` seems to be undocumented behavior.

Comment: I agree, they are the same DOM element, but why does `$.find('#myFormId')` not have any of the functions available that $('body').find('#myFormId') has like `$('body').find('#myFormId').css`

Comment: I searched the APIs and even though `$.find()` seems to work, it is missing context and selectors. You may have stumbled upon something that isn't supposed to actually work. ;)

Comment: Okay, I think functions that should be used in a specific contexts should validate itself, or warn you at least.

Answer (score 0):

```
.find()
```

Should be called on a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, like you do in `$('body').find('#myFormId')`, while the direct use of

```
 $.find()
```

is not in the [documented API](https://api.jquery.com/find/). So you should not expect any particular behaviour, and also what we are observing now (an array is returned) mat change int the future